# How to fix NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: ssl-certificate

My web app was working fine and then suddenly began getting this error. The SSL certificate (Let's Encrypt) has not expired. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: seems like your certificate is expired. when I load the page i get a different certificate which it shows a self-signed one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Sep 30 2021, one of LetsEncrypts root certs expired.  There are various fixes available, but these usually do not affect web sites, but everything else.

In CentOS for example you have to upgrade the ca-certificates package.

In your particular case, if that is indeed the url you're trying to protect (tennispro.pcaps.one), it is not even showing a LetsEncrypt certificate at all.

It's currently showing a Plesk self signed certificate that expired in June 2020.  So first make it pick up the correct certificate, then go from there.